# Screen timeout troubles

Tags: applications

My galaxy note 4 is only staying on for about 15 seconds before timing out. And every time I try to change it a pop-up says that it is set to 15 seconds and I cannot change it. I've turned off stuff and messed with my settings as much as possible and am still not able to fix the problem.

Comment: Are you using a battery optimization program that controls such settings? I don't know if Greenify specifically does this, but I can envision this type of setting might not be overridden by a similar app in this class.

Answer (score -1):

Check as suggested by wbogacz. If it still does not works, restore the settings to factory default. It is better to have default state before we proceed.

Comment: `It is better to have default state before we proceed.` -- Factory reset should be the last resort for anything, except flashing. Its just an overkill for anyone not familiar with backup and restore. I don't see any troubleshooting you suggested.